# Is it possible to connect to a locally running IBM MQ Light with Java and JMS?

Tags: jms, ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

the title of the question says pretty much all: is it possible to connect to a locally running IBM MQ Light with Java and JMS ?
In the comment section of [this post](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2015/02/06/introducing-mq-light-client-java/), Rob Nicholson says it is not possible, but I wonder if things have changed. Sadly, I was not able to find information that explicitly negate this possibility, apart this comment.

Just to clarify, MQ Light runs locally, not in IBM's bluemix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use JMS with MQLight!

As MQLight supports the wire protocol AMQP 1.0 you can use, for instance, the [Apache QPid Proton library](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html).

Working Sample in two files will produce a message to a MQLight queue.

*Main.java*

```
import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            ConnectionFactory cf = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:5672");
            Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("QUE.BAR"));
            producer.send(session.createTextMessage("foo bar"));
            producer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(JMSException jmsException){
            jmsException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mqlight-jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks @Petter, just give my colleagues and me the chance to give it a try on the application we're developing and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: How did this work out?  I'll also mention that via the beta https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/update_to_mq_s_beta_support_for_mq_light?lang=en it is possible to use MQ Light API in MQ stand alone now and this will of course interwork with JMS